# Express Session Cookie not set in Chrome in development mode

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, session-cookies, express-session

I have been fighting this issue for many hours now and I can't get it to work. I'm creating a react app (vite) and for the backend I'm using NodeJS with Express. I'm also using express-session in the backend to handle sessions. For some reason the session cookie is not being set in google chrome. It works fine in Safari and Firefox. I have tried everything that I have found from other answers with similar questions but none have worked so far. I might be missing something but can't figure out what. Here is my backend code. It's important to note that I'm currently only in localhost and in development mode. I have not tried this on Production as the APP is not ready yet.

```
//app.js (backend)

const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { connect, MONGO_URI } = require('./db');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

connect();

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

const FRONTEND_URL = process.env.FRONTEND_URL.split(',') || [
  'http://localhost:5533/',
];

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: FRONTEND_URL,
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.options('*', cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'MySecret$',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 600000,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: true,
    },
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: MONGO_URI,
    }),
  })
);

app.use('/api', require('./routes/index.routes'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

From my react app when Calling the API with Fetch I'm passing the credentials: 'include' option.

```
const response = await fetch(API_URL + '/visitor', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({}),
        credentials: 'include',
      });
```

Any ideas as to why Chrome is not setting the session cookies? Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

As I mentioned Firefox and even Safari works fine, the session cookie is properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the SameSite:'None' attribute in Chrome, you need to serve your application over HTTPS in your development environment. You can use tools like mkcert to set up a local development SSL certificate. Then set secure: true if you are going with this approach. Or you could just conditionally add SameSite=Lax for development environment. Or just remove this line all together in development. 
Also in the development mode, when your application is not running behind a reverse proxy that handles HTTPS termination, you do not need to set app.set('trust proxy', 1). Try something like this instead,

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && app.set('trust proxy', 1)
```

Comment: Thank you Nazrul Chowdhury - by setting sameSite = 'lax' in development worked. So basically in Development I have to set sameStie = 'lax', and secure: false And in production sameSite = 'none' secure = true. Also as a side note, in other for Safari to set the session cookie when in production the backend and frontend needs to be in the same toplevel domain.